# Converting binary value to downloadable zipfile

Tags: java, servlets, zipoutputstream

I have a scenario where I have to convert binary data to zipfile and I have to download it in java.

I am struck with a part how to convert binary to zipformate. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code where you have problems with.

Comment: I don't have the actual code sorry mate. My input is binary data  (not a file) and output is zipfile.. thanks for the reply

Comment: What has this got to do with AEM?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was using this functionality in one of the aem component @lmran saeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow the sample code below to convert your binary data file to zipfile:

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;  
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;  
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;  

class ZipTest {    
    public static void zip(String zipFileName, String inputFile)  
            throws Exception {  
        File f = new File(inputFile);  
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(  
                zipFileName));  
        zip(out, f, f.getName());  
        System.out.println("zip done");  
        out.close();  
    }  

    private static void zip(ZipOutputStream out, File f, String base)  
            throws Exception {  
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(base));  
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);  
        int b;  
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1)  
            out.write(b);  
        in.close();  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            ZipTest t = new ZipTest();  
            t.zip("c:\\test.zip", "c:\\1.txt");  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay Gong :)

Comment: @suryaprakash hope could help you

Comment: Yes it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to convert InputStream to ZipInputStream:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(args[i]);
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
      ZipEntry ze = null;
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Unzipping " + ze.getName());
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(ze.getName());
        for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
          fout.write(c);
        }
        zin.closeEntry();
        fout.close();
      }
      zin.close();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I am using binary data which was a zipfile once,  how can I convert it back the binary data(not a file) to zip file formats again.

Comment: Please don't leave links to unrelated websites under your answers.